# IBM Worklight 6.1 - Build and Deploy not available?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I have used Worklight 5 for Eclipse Juno multiple times and had great success when building hybrid apps for Android and iOS. However, I just recently installed a new version of Eclipse Juno on a new computer and later installed Android ADT and Worklight.

Eclipse works as normal for non-Worklight apps. When I create a Worklight 6.1 project and right-click the common folder, select "Run-As", I am **not** presented with any options to do just that. I am only seeing the options for "Preview and Run configurations" but should be seeing these mentioned options and "Build and Deploy".

Is there something corrupted in Worklight that I need to change to make these options re-appear? Are these options no longer used? If they are not used, how do I deploy a hybrid to Android, iOS, or any other platform?

Answer (score 2):

In Worklight 6.1 they have re-swizzled  the options a bit, but if you want the equivalent of "Build all and Deploy," select: "Run on Worklight Development Server."  You need to select the **App**, not the common folder to get that option.

Answer (score 1):

Since you say you've been using Worklight 5 and have now switched to Worklight 6.1.0, I suggest that you will review the following:

- [What's New in Worklight 6.0.0.0](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.getstart.doc/start/c_what_s_new.html)
- [What's New in Worklight 6.1.0.0](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.getstart.doc/start/c_what_s_new.html)
- [IBM Worklight training modules](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html)

The `Run As > Build and Deploy` action was renamed to `Run As > Run on Worklight Development Server` and additional actions were added as well. You will want to take some time to re-familiarize yourself with the production...

Tip: no need to re-build after every web resource change you make; just refresh your previewed app and the change will be there.

[image]

In the image:

- Run on Worklight Development Server = build and deploy
- Build Android Environment = build only, don't deploy
- Run on Android Studio = if you've installed Android Studio, the built project will open there
- Build Settings and Deploy Target = configurations for minification/concatenation/other as well as changing the server the app will be deployed to, etc.

If you do not see these actions, I think it'd be best if you will get a fresh copy of Eclipse Java EE (4.2.2 ("Juno" SR2) or 4.3.1 ("Kepler" SR1)) and re-install Worklight Developer Edition from the Eclipse Marketplace (or your Consumer/Enterprise Edition if you're a Business Partner/Customer).

Comment: Ian, thanks for the information. I am definitely not getting these options and I have in-fact already read through the Worklight documents. I have already installed Eclipse Juno and Worklight twice. I think something is corrupted...I just don't know what/where.

Comment: Then IMO your installation is skewed. Make sure you use either Eclipse Java EE 4.2.2 ("Juno" SR2) or 4.3.1 ("Kepler" SR1). Try a re-installation.